# Use HTTP as default in IntelliJ or Android Studio

Tags: maven, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, https

I know this may seem like an odd request (which may help explain why no google research is helping me find the answer) but due to some firewall issues, connecting to external resources via HTTPS takes a very long time or times out entirely.

Currently my dependencies look like:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
}
```

And my error woes look like:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18.
     Required by:
         udacity-android-nanodegree--july2015-project1:app:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library/1.0.18/library-1.0.18.pom'.
         > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library/1.0.18/library-1.0.18.pom'.
         > Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused
```

Now, these errors come and go and really depend on the backbone firewall taking its time on the HTTPS requests. If you look close at the error, it references `https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library/1.0.18/library-1.0.18.pom` which, when you strip out the `https` and replace it with just `http` it reveals the same thing.

For connections that need to be secure, HTTPS due to security/logins/etc, its fine, but for downloading public libraries and dependencies, **how do I ensure Android Studio sticks with regular HTTP**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm I think I found my answer. I just need to update my repositories instructions in my gradle script to force it to HTTP:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }
}
```

before it was just `mavenCentral()` which much have been HTTPS based