# Android studio gradle not recognise com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Developing app with Android studio using gradle. I have added this dependencies to it:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

but it says :

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not download gson.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1)
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar'.
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar'.
         > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
```

Full source for my build.gradle files

**Project:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**App:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "domain.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'

}
```

Comment: Add "mavenCentral()" to your repository, like jcenter().

Comment: @ThomasR.  remove jcenter one or append it? i have tested it before. for this reasno i am asking it again

Comment: but only temporary, while you're having connectivity issues with jcenter. jcenter should always be used over mavenCentral() unless you have no choice

Comment: repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            
        }
    }

Comment: The issue here is 99% certain a connectivity issue. If it used to work, this should be temporary issue

Comment: please example. on which gradle make this changes?

Comment: @AEMLoviji See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Define this in you gradle build script.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    ...
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

Comment: Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0

Comment: compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'

Comment: Even after "Sync Project with gradle files"?

Comment: Try without jcenter. Comment this out and try again. Do you have a firewall or something like this?

Comment: if i remove jcenter then it gives another error:
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0

Comment: Ok, try to invalidate caches and restart IDE.

Comment: no success. But very interesting situation, i removed compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' from dependencies and then rtied to sync it. i do not why it is still looks for gson. Very interesting. I have invalidated caches

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91003/discussion-between-aemloviji-and-thomas-r).

Comment: Specifically for me, need both buildscript and allprojects repositories

Answer (score 1):

Call `mavenCentral()` in your **build.gradle** .

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {

 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3' 

}
```

> [add maven repository to build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574111/add-maven-repository-to-build-gradle)
>
> [Failed to resolve: com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581327/failed-to-resolve-com-google-code-gsongson2-3-1)

Comment: same error: 
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not download gson.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1)
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar'.
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar'.
         > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused

Comment: @AEMLoviji Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795957/use-http-as-default-in-intellij-or-android-studio

Comment: i have looked it. not my build.gradle file looks like below. but not works. same erorr. Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused. 
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}

Comment: Very interesting situation for me, if i removed compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' from dependencies and then tried to sync it. I do not understand why it is still looks for gson.