# what is the difference between com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar and com.mcxiaoke.volley:library?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-volley

When I search volley in android studio, get both *com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19* and *com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.1*. But what is the difference? what is the *aar* stand for? Base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32867288/3831668) answer, the one without a *aar* is a newer version, is that right?

Comment: That library is deprecated (2018). Author recomends you use the official Volley version.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a library with different methods in your project.For example:

https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

**This is for Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mcxiaoke.volley</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

**Using SNAPSHOT**

add this to repositories section in build.gradle

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
```

Or the easiest and best way:

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

And of course, The `AAR` file consists of a JAR file and some resource files and that comes from Maven repository.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21485222/4409113

Answer (score 1):

aar is just a file format (like jar). 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format.
the version is what matters. 1.0.19 is newer than 1.0.1