# Failed to resolve dependencies in gradle behind proxy

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proxy, dependencies

```
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: org.quanqi:android-view-pager-indicator:0.9.0
.....

Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1
....
Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1
....
```

My gradle dependencies are

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'org.quanqi:android-view-pager-indicator:0.9.0'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
}
```

my proxy is set in gradle.properties...(credentials not shown)

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=xxxxxx
systemProp.http.proxyHost=x.x.x.x
systemProp.http.proxyUser=xx@x.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

Still gradle build is failing... when I am building the project outside firewall its working perfect, no proxy required then. I am using Android Studio 1.4

I have already tried the following and was not successful:-

[Using ViewPagerIndicator library with Android Studio and Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130003/using-viewpagerindicator-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle)

[Use HTTP as default in IntelliJ or Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795957/use-http-as-default-in-intellij-or-android-studio)

I have already configured proxy settings for Andriod Studio and SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This three r library projects and it is added as

in `build.gradle` import library module as

```
compile project(':library_projectname')
```

The add this line in `settings.gradle`

```
include ':app', ':library_projectname'
```

Comment: That's not working... issue is not in building.. issue comes because gradle cannot fetch the libraries from repositories,,